# How can I open a new Chrome window with javascript automation in yosemite?

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

I'm trying to do something basic. I just want to open a new window and then in that window, open 2 tabs, using OSX Yosemite's new javascript bridge. I can't find docs that show how to do this:

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
chrome = Application("Google Chrome");
chrome.includeStandardAdditions = true
chrome.open("test1tab.com");
chrome.open("test2tab.com");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm ignoring the standardAddiions line, mostly because I used it and it returned an error when trying a basic beep(). **Also note that I had to write out the full url for it to work!**

```
chrome = Application("Google Chrome");
//chrome.includeStandardAdditions = true;
win = chrome.Window().make();
chrome.windows[0].tabs[0].url = "http://www.crgreen.com/index2.html";
tab = win.tabs.push(new chrome.Tab());
chrome.windows[0].tabs[1].url = "http://www.crgreen.com/boethos/";
```

(p.s. I edited a junky version out, then saw you originally wanted 2 tabs, so here you go)

Comment: Thank you, how where you able to know that? I read the dictionary files and didn't see anything about windows.  Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome. window is in the dictionary, under both the Standard Suite and the Chromium Suite; tabs are listed as elements "contained by windows" (Chromium Suite). This page helped: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/

Answer (score 1):

You were close. This works:

```
chrome = Application("Google Chrome");
chrome.includeStandardAdditions = true;
chrome.openLocation("http://test1tab.com");
chrome.openLocation("http://test2tab.com");
```

Notice how:

- The `ObjC` line is unecessary.
- It has to be `openLocation` instead of `open`.
- The URLs need to specify the protocol.